# Arduino Telegram bot Notification message

Tags: arduino, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to create a monitoring system using Arduino, DHT11 and Telegram bot. I tried to send a message for a start but it seems like the connection between the arduino and telegram does not establish. Serial monitor prints out the "TELEGRAM NOT Successfully sent" message. However, it does not give any error. Please help.

---

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <UniversalTelegramBot.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

// Initialize Wifi connection to the router 
#define WIFI_SSID "xxxxx"                                             // input your home or public wifi name 
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "xxxxxx" 

// Initialize Telegram BOT 
#define BOTtoken "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
#define CHAT_ID "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"

//Create a new WiFi client
WiFiClientSecure client; //For ESP8266 boards

//Create a bot with the token and client 
UniversalTelegramBot bot(BOTtoken, client);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600); 
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);                                     //try to connect with wifi
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.print(WIFI_SSID);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);

  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(WIFI_SSID);
  Serial.print("IP Address is : ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  if (bot.sendMessage(CHAT_ID, "Bot started up")){
    Serial.println("TELEGRAM Successfully sent");
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("TELEGRAM NOT Successfully sent");
  }
} 

void loop() {

}
```

---

Comment: You left your bot-token in your question, I've removed it, but it's still there in the questions history. You should renew the bot-token with the help of the [@BotFather](https://t.me/botfather) before people may abuse your bot!

Comment: thank you for reminding me. I've change the bot-token